# Reading data separated by spaces into an array of structures

Tags: c++

I have difficulty reading data from a txt file and converting it into  an array of structures.Data is formatted as follows:

```
John Doe MATH 4 3 4 3 2
John Peterson MATH 5 5 3 6 2
...
```

At the moment, I can only read  no more than *NLENGTH* chars , and among them should be a delimiter character(at least at *NLENGTH + 1* position). But if there is a record with a **name/major** longer than *NLENGTH* , my code stops working correctly. The input for the code below looks like this:

```
    John Doe # MATH # 4 3 4 3 2
    John Peterson# MATH#  5 5 3 6 2
    Michele Jordan # Electrical Engeeniring # 8 7 9 0 3 // Fail on this line
    John Dore# MATH# 5 4 3 2 1
    John Dore# Biology #9 3 4 2 3
```

```
const int NMARK = 5;
const int NLENGTH = 20;
const int NSTUDENT = 100;
const char dataDelimeter = '#';
void from_txtFile(const char *filename, Student *stArray)
struct Student {
    char name[NLENGTH];
    char major[NLENGTH];
    int mark[NMARK];
};
int main()
{
    Student stArray[NSTUDENT];
    char fileName[20] = "data.txt";

    from_txtFile(fileName, st);
}
void from_txtFile(const char *filename, Student *stArray) {
    ifstream data(filename, ios::in);
    int recordCount = 0;
    if (!data) cout << "Error" << endl;
    while (data && (recordCount < NSTUDENT)) {
        data.getline(stArray[recordCount].name, NLENGTH, dataDelimeter);
        data.getline(stArray[recordCount].major, NLENGTH, dataDelimeter);
        for (int i = 0; i < NMARK; i++)
            data >> stArray[recordCount].mark[i];
        // Output
        cout << stArray[recordCount].name << ' ';
        cout << stArray[recordCount].major << ' ';
        for (int i = 0; i < NMARK; i++)
            cout << stArray[recordCount].mark[i] << ' ';
     }
     recordCount++;
     data.close();
}
```

Comment: Can we assume that you are not permitted to replace the `char` arrays with `std::string`? Whole problem goes away with `std::string`.

Comment: Unrelated: no need to specify `ios::in` when working with `ifstream`. `ifstream` implies `ios::in`.

Comment: When [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) is required to read past the given buffer size, it sets and error flag to force you to deal with the error. test the stream states for error, [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error, perform any necessary clean-up, and then continue.

Comment: @user4581301, Thank you, but what if I have 10 fields like this, I need to do that for each?

Comment: @user4581301,If I will use std::string, how can I control the size of fields in struct?

Comment: Every time you take any input from any source you should test it, make sure it is correct, and clean up any messes left before proceeding. Failure to do so is foolhardy as people love entering invalid information into computer programs for fun and profit.

Comment: You could read into a `string` and then test the size. If the size read is too large, you can truncate it to fit, ask the user for better input, or take any other action that seems to fit. Personally I'd make the structure hold `string`s as well and give up on controlling the size. When the input is delimited plaintext, you can expect the lengths will vary and you might as well use a variable-length container.

Comment: @user4581301, I need each structure to be the same size, in order to write arrays of structures to a binary file and read into from a binary file.Can this be done with std::strings?

Comment: Yes, but not easily. It needs to be serialized. `string` is better suited to the sort of free-form data you have as input and not so good for dumping arrays of a fixed-length structure.